# Prevent Storage Buckets from going public

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, policy

I am trying to apply something similar to an Organizational Policy in my Google Cloud Environment to prevent storage buckets from being made public. I have done researched and read through Google's documentation but did not have any success. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an organization to apply organization policies. But you [can create one for free if you own your own domain](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization). No paid GSuite (google workspace) account is required for this, only a domain (and you have domain for $12 per year)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be solvable by using a combination of the GCS Bucket-Only IAM org policy in conjunction with the Domain Restricted Sharing org policy.

Any buckets created under those two org policies will restrict access to IAM and specified domain.

[Restricting identities by domain](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains)

[Organization policy constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)